# SELECT common entities only based on different corresponding entities

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, sql-server-2012

3 Tables

Client -

```
CID    Name
1      Ana
2      Bana
3      Cana
```

ClientProgram (Bridge Table) -

```
CID   PID
1      4
1      5
1      8
2      10
```

Program -

```
PID   Program
4      X
5      Y
8      Z
10     G
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Name    Program
Ana       X
Ana       Y
```

I want to extract only those `Clients` which are common/exist in different `Programs` I choose (say X and Y in this case)

Query attempt:

```
  SELECT 
        C.Name
        ,P.Program
    FROM ClientProgram CP
    INNER JOIN Client C
        ON CP.CID=C.CID
    INNER JOIN Program P
        ON CP.PID=P.PID
    INNER JOIN ClientProgram CP1
        ON CP.CID=CP1.CID

    WHERE P.Program = 'X' OR P.Program = 'Y'
        AND CP.CID = CP1.CID
```

This however doesn't pulls in all clients and not only those which exist in multiple programs.

Comment: please post your attempt as well instead of just asking for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       c.Name
       ,p.Program
       ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.CID) as ProgramCount
    FROM
       Program p
       INNER JOIN ClientProgram cp
       ON p.PID = cp.PID
       INNER JOIN Client c
       On cp.CID = c.CID
    WHERE
       p.Program IN ('X','Y')
)

SELECT Name, Program
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    ProgramCount > 1
```

The use of COUNT(*) over will be a problem if PID is not unique in Programs or if the combination of CID to PID in ClientProgram is not unique.  However I would assume uniqueness based on what I see.

If not you can go a route like this:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       cp.CID
    FROM
       Program p
       INNER JOIN ClientProgram cp
       ON p.PID = cp.PID
    WHERE
       p.Program IN ('X','Y')
    GROUP BY
       cp.CID
    HAVING
       COUNT(DISTINCT p.PID) > 1
)

SELECT
    c.Name
    ,p.Program
FROM
    cte t
    INNER JOIN Client c
    ON t.CID = c.CID
    INNER JOIN ClientProgram cp
    ON t.CID = cp.CID
    INNER JOIN Program p
    ON cp.PID = p.PID
    AND p.Program IN ('X','Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a round about way of doing it. Probably a better way but this will do it. I through in scripts for temp table in case someone else wants to improve. Could do a temp table for example instead of CTE.

```
create table #client(cid int,name varchar(20))
create table #clientprogram (cid int, pid int)
create table #program( pid int, program varchar(20))

insert into #client
values(1,'Ana')
    ,(2,'Bana')
    ,(3,'Cana')

insert into #clientprogram
values (1,4)
        ,(1,5)
        ,(1,8)
        ,(2,10)
        ,(2,4)

insert into #program
values (4,'x')
    ,(5,'y')
    ,(8,'z')
    ,(10,'g')

WITH CHECKPLEASE AS(
Select c.Name,ISNULL(p.Program,p2.PRogram) Program
from #client c
inner join #clientprogram cp
    on c.CID = cp.CID
left join #program p
    on cp.PID = p.PID
    and p.PRogram = 'X'
left join #program p2
    on cp.PID = p2.PID
    and p2.Program = 'Y'
where ISNULL(p.Program,p2.PRogram) is not null
)

Select * 
From CHECKPLEASE
where Name in (
SELECT Name
From CHECKPLEASE
group by Name
having COUNT(*) > 1)
```